# Android ListView Scrolling Visibility of Item

Tags: android, android-listview

How to make sure that after scrolling no partial visible items are there in android listview.They should be all fully visible .

Thanx in advance

Comment: it is unclear what you are asking ? please post code, elaborate your problem and `logcat` if any

Answer (score 2):

Implement onScrollListener 
then, set onScrollListener to ListView

```
@Override
public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
        int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    int lastInScreen = firstVisibleItem + visibleItemCount;

    if(lastInScreen ==  totalItemCount){
        // Fully Visible

    }
}
```

Comment: I don't know if this answers the question because it's unclear but +1 because some day I will use this snippet.